# How to find the best route

Tags: r

everyone. I have an issue to resolve but not much clue. It was presented to me a travelling salesman problem and there are some criteria to attend. It is needed to find the most lucrative route that would take less time. Eventually, it will be more criteria, but learning to resolving this one will let me do any kind of job like this.

```
> glimpse(problem)
Rows: 62
Columns: 5
$ Location_x   <dbl> 27, 20, 29, 26, 22, 23, 22, 24, 25, 23, 30, 27, 21, 22, 21, 24,…
$ Location_y   <dbl> 72, 74, 70, 80, 78, 72, 73, 77, 74, 77, 75, 80, 71, 77, 80, 80,…
$ house_id     <chr> 146, 170, 171, 137, 121, 178, 163, 119, 113, 114, 199, 162, 102…
$ Payment      <dbl> 5378, 7971, 5831, 3303, 6602, 1268, 5371, 1927, 653, 4583, 839,…
$ Days_needed  <dbl> 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, …

> glimpse(workers)
Rows: 8
Columns: 1
$ Professional <chr> "Joe", "Harry", "Jefferson", "Anie", "Donovan", "Jessica", "Leo…
```

I must find a way to move the workers between the houses in a way that profit will come in less time possible. It is the first time that an heuristical (I think it is heuristical) problem comes to me and I'm confused.

Comment: I think the best way to solve your problem is to use a genetic algorithm. First, you need to define a fitness function that minimises cost and time. Take a look at the `GA' package.

Comment: I think this problem is not completely defined: i.e. do you want the workers to finish all the houses in the minimum time or you want to generate first revenues as soon as possible (possibly at the expense of total time)? In the latter case, the criteria to drive the objective function are not defined.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Actually I've been trying GA but I got stuck at some point and geosphere, which I was stuck in converting my locations into matrix and then into a "dist" object (didn't even know that existed this kind of object)